# How applying the gradient descent method for solving a least square problem can remove the blur from an image?

Tags: constrained-optimization, least-squares, image-processing

I got an assignment where it asked to implement (in MATLAB) the gradient descent algorithm in order to resolve an ill posed least square problem:

$$
\min_u \Vert Gu - f \Vert
$$

where $u$ is the reconstructed image, $G$ is the blur applied to $u$ and $f$ is the blurred image.

I have successfully implemented it with MATLAB, it is effectively removing a portion of the applied blur, but I do not understand why applying a gradient descent method to this ill posed least square problem can effectively remove the blur from an image.

Comment: shouldn't this be $\min_u$ not $\min_f$?

Comment: The answer is because you're solving the equation $G u = f$. In other words, you're finding an image $u$ that when blurred produces $f$

Comment: I assume it should also minimize the *square* of the norm.

Comment: I have to admit that I don't understand the question. Why would it *not* remove the blur?

Comment: How badly conditioned is the $G$ matrix?  If it's not badly conditioned, then gradient descent should work (albeit slowly) to minimize the difference between Gu and f.

Comment: I have a question: how do we know G? Just curious, I haven't got any experience in this area. Wouldn't there be different kinds of blurs, each giving a different matrix?

Comment: I don't see any squares? You forgot to square the norm. You even forgot to mention which norm you're using.

Comment: Minimizing the square of the norm is the same as minimizing the norm.  However, the norm type does matter for the algorithm, although not for the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is equivalent to:

$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{u}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{G} \boldsymbol{u} - \boldsymbol{f} \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

The solution is given by $ \hat{\boldsymbol{u}} = {\left( \boldsymbol{G}^{T} \boldsymbol{G} \right)}^{-1} \boldsymbol{G}^{T} \boldsymbol{f} $.
Basically inverting the operation of $ \boldsymbol{G} $ on $ \boldsymbol{f} $.

The Gradient Descent is just a way to solve the problem.
So once it is converged, it is equivalent to the closed form solution.

**Remarks**

- If you solve this actual formulation of the problem, Gradient Descent is a poor choice as it is slow. You may improve it with some acceleration (Momentum / Nesterov) or use Conjugate Gradient.
- This is an inverse problem. In practice it is usually solved with added regularization.

Comment: Also gradient descent has poor convergence - it is equivalent to a Richardson iteration/explicit Euler which are one of the simplest and slowest methods (at least without acceleration strategies). They ought to use the conjugate gradient for the normal equations or variants of it.

Comment: @lightxbulb, I agree. Please feel free to edit the answer and add your insightful remarks.

Comment: Feel free to add it in. I feel uncomfortable editing other's people posts. It's probably also fine if it stays in the comments.

Comment: @lightxbulb, By the way, in practice you'd usually solve such inverse problem with some regularization. Then, I think, CG becomes irrelevant, right?

Comment: CG/CGNR with an initial guess zero results in the Moore-Penrose solution $u^+=G^+f$, so the regularizer is built in, i.e. $\min_{u}\|u\|$.

Comment: @lightxbulb, You mean it will solve for the minimum norm solution. In my experience it is not enough. Usually you add some regularization on the gradients of the answer etc... I think I saw once how to utilize CG for LASSO like solutions, but it is common to use ADMM or something like that.

Comment: Yes, it will solve for the minimum norm solution provided your initial guess is zero. If the initial guess is not zero and it has components in the kernel then those would remain. The constraint $\min_u \|u\|$ is definitely enough. This constraint plus the minimisation problem gives a unique solution, note that the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is unique. Now you could argue that you want some other specific solution, however that wasn't secified in the question. An $L_1$ regularizer like you mention promotes sparsity, e.g. it would make sense if you work in the DCT/DFT or wavelet domain.

Comment: @lightxbulb. I agree. It is not in the question. Just practically you'd add regularization. Anyhow, found what I looked for.  See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87500. At the bottom of my answer I link to a paper using CG for Total Variation regularization.